# Why does the first query work and not the second one?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the data I'm using.

Why does this query work:

`const q = query(ref, where('courseTitle', '==', 'THIRD lesson'));`

but not this one?
`const q = query(ref, where('id', '==', '3WX1MrQ4CLvZG2sKx8dn'));`

i just cannot get data by id. That's the uid of the document right?

Thank you, I'm a novice, so any help is appreciated.

> ```
> * 0
>    * courseDescription: "second" 
>      courseTitle: "second course"
>       email: "t@t.com" 
>      id: "3WX1MrQ4CLvZG2sKx8dn" 
>      owner: "HUXw5YSMEsVPQuABktlmYnPlCRk1" 
>      publishCourse: "checked" 
>      teacher: "tony"
> ```

> ```
>    * 1 :  
>    * courseDescription: "jkjlk;lkj;lj;lkj"
>       courseTitle: "THIRD lesson"
>       email: "t@t.com" 
>      id: "OghdGBf61qGa6ckLqcaf" 
>      owner: "HUXw5YSMEsVPQuABktlmYnPlCRk1"
>       publishCourse: true 
>      teacher: "tony"
> ```

> ```
>      2 :  
>      courseDescription: "this is first"
>       courseTitle: "first course" 
>      email: "t@t.com" 
>      id: "QyY2RBfNIfoCMWOFS5kh" 
>      owner: "HUXw5YSMEsVPQuABktlmYnPlCRk1"
>       publishCourse:  "checked" 
>      teacher: "tony" [[Prototype]] :  Object
> ```

Comment: A field called `id` and the actual id of a document (that you use to to create document references, and must be unique within a collection) are not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug commented, if you query on `id`, Firestore looks for a field named `id` in the document's data. Most likely you actually want to filter on the document ID, which is not part of the document data. To filter on that, use [`documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#documentid).

```
const q = query(ref, where(documentId(), '==', '3WX1MrQ4CLvZG2sKx8dn'));
```